# How to make the device named /dev/mmcblk0 to appear as a file in the filesystem?

Tags: linux, mount, sd-card

I'm trying to adapt an existing `SD/MMC` card driver to our SD controller hardware.
 I'm using `Synopsys' dw_mmc` code (in `linux3.3`) as a reference. I have a long way to go but at least it's compiled ok and the platform device and platform driver seems to have been registered.
 My question is how to make the `/dev/mmcblk0` file appear in the system? I named our new device `ald_sd` and I can see `ald_sd.0` under `/sys/devices/platform`. under `/dev`, I tried `'mknod mmcblk0 179 0'` and I see `mmcblk0` under `/dev`. Then I tried `'mount /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt/sd'` (after making `/mnt/sd`) and it gives me message `'mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0 on /mnt/sd failed: No such device or address'`. 
Please help. Thank you!
Chan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's been several months since I sloved this problem. long story short, when the kernel reads the super block of the SD card, then the block access is ok. usually we make /dev/sd0 using mknod command.(not mmcblock0). (mmcblock0 file is made somewhere different maybe /sys.. I don't remember). Also beware, you can mis-type mknod like mkdir or mkdev, then you can have 'No such device or address' message too. Just for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Your command was absolutely right. Except that you forgot to specify if it was a character device `c` or a block device `b`. instead add a b like this `mknod mmcblk0 b 179 0`. It is a commond mistake I see these days.